# How to use deep destructuring on imports in ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I noticed that an ES6 destructuring import can be implemented like this:

**foo.js**

```
export default () => {
  return {
    a: 'b'
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import foo from './foo';
export default foo;
export const bar = foo();
```

Then I can use the module with:

```
import foo, { bar } from 'my-module';
```

But when I use a "deep destructuring" import from `my-module`, it fails with:

```
import foo, { bar: { a } } from 'my-module';
```

It seems like ES6 already implements the above syntax, but how do I use it?

Comment: You can't. Import uses a syntax, which is very similar to destructuring, but not identical. See this article [ES6 JavaScript Destructuring in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth) (special case: import at the end).

Comment: @OriDrori  thanks, I get my mistake ..

Comment: Even if you *could*, you probably shouldn't. That would be violating the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The *ImportClause* of an `import` isn't the same as destructuring. They do have some syntactic similarity, but if you read through [the spec on `import`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-imports), you can see that it never refers to the usual destructuring constructs such as *DestructuringAssignmentTarget* or *BindingPattern*.

Remember that imports create *bindings* between the modules, but destructuring assignments copy *values* from a source to a target. With your imagined destructuring import, if the value of `bar` changes in the source module, would that change your imported `a`? (After all, with `import { bar } from 'my-module';`, if `bar` changes in `my-module`, the imported `bar` reflects that change.) Or would the destructuring import copy the value of `bar.a` to `a` as of some point in time? And if so, what point in time?

You get the idea. They're just different beasts.

You can, of course import and *then* destructure:

```
import foo, { bar } from 'my-module';
let { a } = bar;
```

...but I'm sure you knew that. :-)

Comment: Just opinion. Not to this answer. But they should have made this same as destructuring. Not sure why they didn't simplify this. Moreover, instead of "import" they could use existing const, let like CommonJs is doing. new syntaxes weren't required. Could have avoided some boilerplate syntaxes. "from" can still be digested as that is totally new concept to bring things from other files. But that could have been used as a function too like `from('./my-module')`

Comment: @AnonymousCreator - I think it stems from the fact that this is an entirely new, static, declarative mechanism for expressing relationships between modules, so using new syntax makes good sense. If they made it use a `from` pseudo-function like yours, it would look like the old CommonJS dynamic thing, which would be misleading. And making it static was a smart move IMHO. It enabled smooth handling of circular dependencies, smart pre-fetching, and bundler-time tree-shaking amongst other things. What would it mean to do static analysis on a deeply destructured import ...

Comment: ... like `const {x: [{y}]} = from("./mod.js");`? How would you even export that? As an object with an `x` property? Then you're doing live bindings to object properties (because remember, import bindings are *live* bindings; they see changes to the exported member), impacting the entire object mechanism of the language, which is already plenty complicated. Then there's the issue that if `from` is a function, you can assign to an object property as the target of the binding, or even pass it into another function instead (`doSomethingWith(from("./my-module.js"))`). That causes all kinds ...

Comment: ... of complications. :-) So no, I think new syntax and a static mechanism were the right choices. **My** quibble is them using `{}` at all, causing this superficial resemblance in the first place. I would have gone with just `import a, b as whatever, c from "./my-module.js";`. (I wouldn't have had default exports at all, or if absolutely necessary, just had you use `default` to refer to them when importing.). But decisions get made by the people in the room, and I wasn't in the room (nor am I ever likely to be). :-)

Comment: (I should note that for the use cases where dynamic allows things static doesn't, they did add an `import()` pseudo-function very like your `from`, but where it always gives you all of the imports, so it's not friendly to tree-shaking. And you can indeed destructure what it gives you [if you await it], but you lose the live binding. I do think they were right to use a static mechanism as the primary one.)