# Object destructuring assignment works with Node but not with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-modules, playwright

'Using the Playwright Library [`1.21.0`] with Jest [`27.5.1`] to run browser automation tests on Node.js [`14.18.2`].

ESM is the current module format.

```
// package.json
...
"type": "module",
...
```

I setup a quick test with the following code:

```
// playwright-hello.js

import {chromium} from 'playwright';

async function main() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('http://www.example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });

  await browser.close();
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

The above code works via CLI command `node playwright-hello` with no issues.

However, when I try to run similar code with Jest, I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  test/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: The requested module 'playwright' does not provide an export named 'chromium'

      at Runtime.linkAndEvaluateModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:779:5)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

I fixed this by updating the test code to use the default export instead:

```
// changed to use default export instead of named one
import playwright from 'playwright';

// prepended `playwright.` to initial `chromium.launch()`
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
```

How come the object destructuring assignment in `playwright-hello.js` [i.e. `import {chromium}...`] works with `node.js` CLI, but not with `Jest`? In other words, `node.js` did not complain about `playwright` library not providing a named export, why?

> **Note**: I'm running Jest as follows for ES6 modules support:
>
> ```
> NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' npx jest ./test/index
> ```

Comment: There is no destructuring in `import {chromium} from 'playwright';`. That's importing a named export, not doing destructuring. Despite the fact they both use `{}`, they are very different things. It looks like you've run into a bit of "fun" with regard to the way Node.js handles the interface between ESM and CommonJS and/or the way the `playwright` library handles ESM vs. CommonJS. But the main thing is that import syntax is not destructuring. :-) *(NOT my downvote)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot for the explanation on destructuring; I'll have to study more on the subject as it appears I have the wrong impression.  Looking at `./node_modules/playwright/index.mjs`, there doesn't appear to be a named export; 'makes me wonder why the example works in the first place. For now, I'll stick with the default import and move on. And downvotes are actually a great thing when they come with explanation/direction/instruction, so no issues even if it was you :-).

Comment: Looking at it more closely, the issue isn't why the Node.js code worked, but why the Jest code didn't. :-) `playwright` **does** have a named `chromium` export in its ESM module: `./node_modules/playwright/index.mjs` has `export * from 'playwright-core';` which re-exports all of `playwright-core`'s named exports. If we look at `./node_modules/playwright-core/index.mjs`, we can see `export const chromium = playwright.chromium;` -- a named export for `chromium`. So somewhere along the line, Jest's handling of ESM isn't working correctly (I've seen lots questions about it here). So despite...

Comment: ...your mentioning "destructuring," I don't think this is answered by questions I'd linked as originals ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137896/how-to-use-deep-destructuring-on-imports-in-es6-syntax) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456575/es5-exported-function-not-recognized)). So I've voted to re-open. The ends up being primarily a question about Jest's handling of ESM (and may be something you want to report in their issues list).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the detailed breakdown. I'll definitely be looking more closely into how imports work behind the scenes. I also appreciate you reopening this. I couldn't get much info from the linked references after the closing.